# How to load ASP.NET big HTML table async

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, performance

I have an ASP.NET page with a HTML table that is being built this way:

```
<tbody>
                      <%Dim i As Integer = 0

                          For i = 0 To Subscribers.Count - 2
                      %>
                    <tr>
                      <td><%=Subscribers(i).Token%></td>                       
                      <td><%=Subscribers(i).MerchantName%></td>
                      <td><%=Subscribers(i).FirstName%></td>
                      <td><%=Subscribers(i).LastName%></td>
                      <td><%=Subscribers(i).State%></td>
                    </tr>
                      <%Next%>
                  </tbody>
```

now, I have more than 1500 records and it takes alot of time to load it.
Whats the easiest way to load those 1500 records without letting the user wait for the whole table to be loaded, but to show them the records as they come?

I am using datatables.net

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered paging?

Comment: AJAX call to a web service returning X rows at a time? Or an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with other suggestions to either introduce some kind of a paging mechanism. But if you want to keep your current code and simple display rows to users as they come - add one line of code before your `Dim`:

```
Response.Buffer = False
```

This will disable page buffering and output data right away row by row.